# Is Nebula actually helping Thanos?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

It bothered me so much in *Avengers: Infinity War* that just when they were getting the gauntlet off Thanos, Nebula revealed that

> Gamora was killed by Thanos

I get that it's emotional outburst and don't want to sound insensitive but she could have waited to reveal this until after the gauntlet was off Thanos' hand! It was just convenient that what she did was a sureshot way of emotionally derailing

> Quill and the others

thereby giving Thanos a chance to get his Gauntlet back.

Also in the beginning, when Nebula is being tortured by Thanos, just right after the place where the soul stone is kept is revealed, she manages an escape. I feel she could have escaped earlier if she tried to.

So is Nebula actually helping Thanos get the all the stones? She seemed so, so sketchy! Is there any genuine source that can shed light on Nebula's actions?

Comment: If she is, it will be revealed in *Avengers 4* - Until then this is opinion-based.

Comment: Maybe. Maybe she's also slightly insane though. She hasn't had an easy life.

Comment: Im trying to get facts - facts that shes either with Thanos or against Thanos. Not at all trying to get my opinion across.

Comment: If she was working with Thanos she wouldn't have had to escape after he and Gamora left for the soul stone.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

At the end of *Guardians of the Galaxy 2*, Nebula goes off on her own and (IIRC) tells Gamora that she intends to kill Thanos. When Thanos shows Gamora the captured Nebula, he states that he'd caught Nebula sneaking onto his ship to try and do just that.

Nebula could not have escaped during her torture because... well... she was being tortured. *Horribly*. Her whole body was being pulled apart. It was only after Thanos had gotten what he wanted and ended the torture that she was able to escape (note how when she escapes, she's been put back together again).

As for the outburst, there are two things to bear in mind there. Firstly, Nebula is not the most emotionally stable person (she spends most of *GotG2* in a single-minded, homicidal rage). Secondly,

> Gamora was Nebula's adopted sister, and as of the end of *GotG2*, they appear to have gotten quite close. It's understandable that Nebula would be too upset by her death - especially at the hands of Thanos, whom she hates - to be able to control her emotions.

So the evidence seems to point to **no**. Nebula hates Thanos' guts and, while her outburst may have helped him *accidentally*, she almost certainly did *not* help him on purpose.

Comment: I agree with your line of thoughts. I think she didn't think of _helping Thanos_, she was grieving too, for her sister's death, and she just wanted to shout/point out who the murderer was. IMHO

Comment: Ok, i see your point, maybe i was reading way too much into her actions. I did read an article (i think maybe unofficial) which said Gamora and Nebula had a friction as well, and her being the less loved daughter

Comment: Good answer.  It is also worth noting that Nebula has a very difficult time controlling her emotions and outbursts, and very often acts on her anger without thinking ahead.